# CSS - max-width Causes Spacing Issue In Parent

Tags: html, css, max, min

I have two DIVs on my site, both set to `display: inline-block`. Setting `width: auto` on the parent should cause it to use only the space occupied by the child.

However, when I use a large `width` on the child but override it with `max-width` and `min(...)` the parent size ignores the width (large whitespace on the right). In the following example you can clearly see that the `max-width` gets applied, but the `auto` keyword ignores it and stretches the parent anyway.

I want the parent element to only use the horizontal space necessary. Any idea on how to fix it? Thanks!

```css
.wrapper-1{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.hello-world{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5000px;
  max-width: min(100px, 100%);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <div class="wrapper-2">
    <div class="hello-world">Hello, world!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the use of percentage is the issue. You want a fix or a long explanation?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, you are right! It works without the percentage. I'd prefer a solution that can achieve this effect, using percentage.

Comment: ask yourself one question: percentage of what? the parent width depend on the content and the same for the content. So percentage of what?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Of the first block element ancestor, in this case the body, it does seem to work that way for the width too. But I get your point, I probably misunderstood how the percentage works exactly in this case.